# Conta nós em árvores binárias

Tags: c, recursão

Boa noite, estou estudando árvores binárias e me deparei com um exercício que pede pra contar os nós. Imitei adaptando um algoritmo que calcula altura e deu certo...

```
int conta_nos (arvore *r) { 
    if (r == NULL) return 0;
    else {          
        int conte = conta_nos (r->esq);         
        int contd = conta_nos (r->dir); 
        return conte + contd + 1;   
    }
}
```

Porém não entendi muito bem, já carrego dúvidas de recursão e acredito que isso seja o ponto da minha dúvida. Nessa questão declarei duas variáveis pra receber o que vem da esquerda e da direita e no retorno somei as duas e acrescentei 1. Daí segue, se tiro o "+ 1" do retorno ele zera a quantidade de nós, entendi que toda vez que passa por um dos nós ele soma 1, blz, mas, o que recebe essas duas variáveis conte e contd, antes disso tentei retornar `return conta_nos(r->esq) + conta_nos(r->dir) + 1;` mas não deu muito certo, como escrevi carrego dúvidas de recursão e sinto que estão me atrapalhando em árvores.

Comment: Certeza que `return 1 + conta_nos(r->esq) + conta_nos(r->dir);` não funcionou? Pois deveria

Comment: Posso ter feito algo errado, vou verificar, mas ainda tenho dúvida sobre o que recebe as duas variáveis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa é uma função [recursiva](http://linguagemc.com.br/recursividade-em-c/), portanto ela itera até o limite chamando a si mesma depois volta retornando valores desejados paras as chamadas superiores.

Uma função recursiva é feita de 3 coisas:

1. Uma condicional para parar a recursividade
2. Uma chamada própria
3. O retorno de um valor

Basicamente o que essa sua função faz é caminha até o extremo direito e esquerdo de cada lado da arvore. Por exemplo,vamos pensar no penúltimo nó da arvore ao chamar essa linha

```
int conte = *conta_nos (r->esq);*
```

retornará  no caso os valores `conte = 0` e `contd = 0` portanto agora o valor de `conte` será 1.

o mesmo vale para linha

```
int contd = conta_nos (r->dir);
```

Portanto teremos no penúltimo no da arvore, depois da iteração das duas chamadas da função, valores `conte = 1` e `contd = 1` ( que representam as folhas da arvore associadas à esse penúltimo nó) e ao fazer o return para o nó superior este vai retornar o valor de `conte` e `contd` acima somando mais 1 que representa ela mesma. O `return` mostrará que têm 3 nós abaixo para o nó superior.